# Meaning of a term in the residual variance

Tags: regression, residuals

Studying my course notes about regression, the assumptions about the residuals are put this way:

$$\varepsilon  \sim {N_n}\left( {0,{\sigma ^2}{I_n}} \right)$$

There are two things that bug me - are those little "n" referring to the dimension of the model? And what about the $I_n$?

Searching for this on google wasn't of much help since I can't use math notation to be specific. Thanks a lot for any input!

Comment: These are not usually called "residuals."  Residuals are the differences between data and fitted values.  Your $\varepsilon$ are usually called "errors."  They are a theoretical construct and do not depend on data.  And yes, when someone uses a capital letter to denote a covariance, they almost always intend it to be a matrix, whence $I_n$ should be understood as the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Usually its meaning is clear from the context.

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong - is the use of the identity matrix in the formula to specify that there's no covariance between the error terms?

Comment: It means two things: first, the covariance between different components is zero.  Second, the variances of each of the error components are the same value $\sigma^2.$

Comment: Thank you, got it.